# NotFoundHttpException No query results for model [App\Post] laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

i am writing this code in my ***postController*** for checking the post exists or not. but the first part of **if conduction** is working but the else is not working, its showing me

> (2/2) NotFoundHttpException No query results for model [App\Post].

```
    $post = Post::findOrFail($post->id);

    if(count($post)>0)
    {
        return view('posts.show',compact('post'));
    }
    else{
        return view('404error');
    }
```

the purpose of this code is, if post found the Good else redirect it to 404 page.
Url of my page is some thing like this.
i am just learning the laravel, and on beginner level

> http://laravel5.prc/posts/4

Can any body guide me. thanks in advance

Comment: from where you are getting this $id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to remove typehinting (Post $post) and replace it to this:

```
public function show($id) 
{ 
    // 
        $post = Post::find($id); 

    if($post) 
    { 
        return view('posts.show',compact('post')); 
    } 
    else{ 
        return view('404error'); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: i tried this bro but same issue insted of going to 404error page its showing again same issue, `(2/2) NotFoundHttpException
No query results for model [App\Post].`

Comment: At what line?? using find() will return null if nothings found it wont throw that exeption.

Comment: its on `(2/2) NotFoundHttpException
No query results for model [App\Post].
in Handler.php (line 131)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154249/discussion-between-anders-and-umair-mehmood).